# new Date().getUTCDay() is different than the variable it is assigned to

Tags: javascript

Currently, I'm using a variable to hold the current date as i build a timer for a countdown. I actually use several variables to hold key pieces of the date when people first load the page.

```
var currentDay  = new Date().getUTCDay();
var currentDate = new Date().getUTCDate();
var currentHour = new Date().getUTCHours()-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()/60);
var currentMinute = new Date().getUTCMinutes();
var currentYear = new Date().getUTCFullYear();
```

This is supposed to be the starting point for what the timer will be counting down from and the formula works fine 90% of the time but i caught a 'NAN' error on the mobile version recently as we crossed from Saturday to Sunday. On desktop, it works perfectly so i tested and checked to see what currentDay is today. it returned 6 (which is saturday) BUT when i just use new Date().getUTCDay(), it gives me 0 (which is Sunday). any idea why there's a discprepancy?

I don't add anything to these variables and yet I'm getting that discrepancy. For the upcoming tuesday, the first date (which is the countdownto) is based on the following:

```
// Start on Tuesday at 11AM Function()
function startOnTuesdayEleven() {
firstDay = 2; firstHour = 11; firstMinute = 0; firstAmOrPm = "AM";
countdownHour = firstHour; countdownMinute = firstMinute; // Tues at 11AM

if(currentDay = 6) { firstDay = firstDay + 7; }   
if(currentDate + firstDay - currentDay > daysInMonth) {
firstMonth = (currentMonth + 1);
firstDate = (currentDate + Math.abs((firstDay) - currentDay)) - daysInMonth;
} else {
firstMonth = currentMonth;
firstDate = currentDate + Math.abs((firstDay) - currentDay);
}
firstDay = findDay(firstDay);
firstHour = findHour(firstHour);
firstMinute = findMinute(firstMinute);
firstMonth = findMonth(firstMonth);
firstDate = findDate(firstDate);
```

again, this has worked fine, up until now, so trying to discern why a variable that is supposed to hold the date object initially, is different than if i just call the object itself on inspection.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBvYH.png)

Comment: `if(currentDay = 6)` is wrong — should be `==` or `===`, not `=`.

Comment: Also you don't really have to do most of that work; the native JavaScript Date API allows you to "move" forward or back through time by adding/subtracting values from individual fields.

Comment: I fixed the currentDay = 6 syntax as soon as i posted it, since i noticed it, but the main question is regarding the currentDay = new Date().getUTCDay; issue. For some reason the variable i get is different than the object that it is assigned to.

Comment: Could you provide a runnable sample?

Comment: Not sure if the image posted earlier that showed my inspect. if it's not clear, what can I provide as I'm still newer to stack overflow so don't want to paste something that's not allowed.

Comment: Again, I'd advise you to stop wasting time debugging it. You can move forward by (say) an hour with `someDate.setHour(someDate.getHour() + 1);` and JavaScript will do all the necessary rollovers.

Comment: that i can work with. I just have to overhaul the code a little bit, but it's not that much work. Thank you @Pointy